# Access local file by intercepting form request?

Tags: javascript

I want to access a local file (read-only) chosen by the user. I know that's not possible with JavaScript (at least not currently and in all browsers).

However it *is* possible to upload a file using an HTML `form` and an `input`  with `type=file`. Now, obviously, when the user clicks on the submit button, the browser needs to read the file into memory and put it into the request body. So, in principle, read-only access to the file system already exists.

I want to somehow intercept that request, read the file contents from the request body into a variable, and stop the request from being send to the server.

Is that at all possible or am I dreaming?

(I know that there are similar questions, but they are either slightly different in what they ask for or the answer requires HTML5.)

Comment: Can you explain why you need to intercept it? If you wan't to avoid the page refreshing you can use ajax calls. You'd still have to send the data but your user won't notice

Comment: @yuvi: I don't want the data to be sent at all. The data might be some sensible information, like an encryption key, and I simply want to access it locally.

Comment: You can't "intercept" the request. Using HTML5's File API would be the only way to do this.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's what I feared.